# protractor: test for focus of field

Tags: angularjs, testing, protractor, end-to-end

How can I test if an input field is infocus with protractor?  I'm doing this:

```
it('should focus email field', function(){
    expect(element(by.model('login.email')).getAttribute('id')).toEqual(browser.driver.switchTo().activeElement().getAttribute('id'));
});
```

This seems to work with chrome, but this test fails with firefox.  Any ideas?

This is the failure message:

```
[firefox #1]   2) Login page should focus email field
[firefox #1]    Message:
[firefox #1]      Expected 'login' to equal ''.
[firefox #1]    Stacktrace:
[firefox #1]      Error: Failed expectation
[firefox #1]     at [object Object].<anonymous> (/Users/Jason/Desktop/app/test/e2e/login-spec.js:38:69)
[firefox #1]
```

Here's my test script:

```
describe('Login page', function() {
    var loginURL = 'http://localhost:8090/app/#/login';
    var loginEmailField = 'login-email';

    beforeEach(function() {
        browser.get(loginURL);
    });

    it('should focus email field', function(){     
        expect(element(by.id(loginEmailField)).getAttribute('id')).toEqual(browser.driver.switchTo().activeElement().getAttribute('id'));
    });
});
```

Comment: Could you provide the error you get when it fails? Thanks.

Comment: Could you please show the whole contents of the spec including `beforeEach` calls? Thanks.

Comment: Updated with whole spec

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to *wait for angular* before making any assertions:

```
beforeEach(function() {
    browser.get(loginURL);
    browser.waitForAngular();
});
```

Aside from that, this might be connected to the `autofocus` attribute, it has/had issues in Firefox, see:

- [Autofocus Attribute of HTML5 does not work only in FireFox when <Form><input> are loaded via Ajax. WHY?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9955398/autofocus-attribute-of-html5-does-not-work-only-in-firefox-when-forminput-ar)
- [Why doesn't autofocus=“autofocus” work in Mozilla Firefox?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/15020/why-doesnt-autofocus-autofocus-work-in-mozilla-firefox)

Comment: Thanks for this.  Good to know.  But this doesn't fix the issue.  Firefox still fails, while chrome doesn't fail.  Strange.

Comment: Gives error - 'TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'activeElement''

Comment: I should say, setting focus on the input field is done via a directive: <input id="login-email" type="email" name="login" placeholder="email" ng-model="login.email" autoFocus>  Does this cause the issue?

Comment: @Jason yup, I think your last comment is a key to solving it. Looks like there are problems with `autofocus` on Firefox, see http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/15020/why-doesnt-autofocus-autofocus-work-in-mozilla-firefox and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9955398/autofocus-attribute-of-html5-does-not-work-only-in-firefox-when-forminput-ar. What firefox version are you using?

Comment: Firefox version 34.  Let me have a look at these links

Comment: Yep.  This was it.  I had written a directive for autofocus, but used it incorrectly.  duh!