# Protractor: How to test if input field is selected (in focus, ready to type text in)

Tags: angular, protractor

How can you test if the focus is on an input field?

I tried doing it like this:
in my .po.ts

```
getEditInputField(fieldName: string) {
    return $(`input[data-e2e=${fieldName}]`)
  }
```

In my .spec.ts

```
it("should focus the Abschlag input field", async () => {
    expect(await budgetBilling.getEditInputField("Abschlag").isSelected()).toBe(true)
})
```

But if i test the test like `.toBe(false)`, protractor lets the test pass in both cases. But it should fail in the case of `toBe(false)`.

Then I found this solution:
[protractor: test for focus of field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27767553/protractor-test-for-focus-of-field)

and used it like this:

```
it("should focus the Abschlag input field", async () => {
    // await browser.waitForAngular() 
 expect(await budgetBilling.getEditInputField("Abschlag").getAttribute('id')).toEqual(await browser.driver.switchTo().activeElement().getAttribute('id'))
  })
```

And the test passes as expected. But if I change it to `getEditInputField("something")` and "something" is also an input field on the same form, but not selected/focused, the test also passes. But it should fail in this case.
And the `waitForAngular()` included or not does not seem to matter.

Am I doing something wrong or has someone a good idea how to test in protractor if a field is selected/focused?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you added `id` attributes to the `input` elements or are they blank? In your case I guess you do not have to compare `id` and can instead compare the data attribute:

```
expect(browser.driver.switchTo().activeElement().getAttribute('data-e2e')).toEqual('Abschlag')
```

Comment: You are absolutely right. I dont have the attribute 'id' on my element. To use 'data-e2e' works perfectly.

Thank you :)